# How do I set up a SQLiteConnection on Windows?

Tags: c#, sqlite, portable-class-library

I am using this nuget package: [SQLite.Net-PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/) to read data from a SQLite Database in my integration Test library.

Previously when doing this I wrote the following code to initialise a `SQLiteConnection`

```
var plat = new SQLite.Net.Platform.Win32.SQLitePlatformWin32();
return new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(plat, "MyDatabasePath");
```

To do this I had to add another nuget package: [SQLite.Net PCL - Win32 Platform](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net.Platform.Win32/)  but this package has now been delisted.

I would like to create another test library for a different project but as the nuget package I was using has been delisted I can no longer use this method to create a `SQLiteConnection`

So what is the correct way to create a `SQLiteConnection` on windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this is the correct way to set up a `SQLiteConnection` but due to a bug in the way the nuget package was packaged. My library could not see the `Win32` namespace.

More info on the bug: https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/issues/310